# Is there a better term for frequency distribution of a term frequency?

Tags: distributions, terminology, frequency

I am wondering if there is a better way of formulating this and also if this is a correct way of formulating it.

What I'm trying to represent in the frequency distribution is the count of documents that contain a certain count of the term I'm interested in. For example, the document sample contains 50 documents with 1 occurrence of the term, 30 documents with 2 occurrences, 10 with 3, and so on.

I'm looking to answer three questions: 1. is *frequency distribution of a term frequency* a correct way to formulate what I described, 2. if yes, is it clear what I mean, and 3. is there a better way to formulate it?

Comment: This is as much a question of English style as of statistical correctness. "Frequency distribution of number of occurrences" or "distribution of number of occurrences" sounds fine to me. Be careful about using the word "frequency" twice. However,  I've seen people refer to frequencies of frequencies. E.g. in ecology 150 species that each occur once.

Answer (score 0):

The language appropriate for demonstrating the distribution of frequencies of occurrence of a key word in a series of documents is a [frequency histogram](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/frequency-histogram.html). If this were my data, 1) sample 10000 (or some other number) words from each document without replacement (called [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))). 2) I would normalize the data as key word occurrences per 10000 words of document for each document, and then 3) find a best density function approximation of that data to characterize it (Using a [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html) in Mathematica or equivalent).  That would have the advantage at the end of the day of giving statistical properties for the rate of key word occurrences on a per document basis.